# How to import a existing iLog rules jar into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud, validationrules

I am trying to import existing iLog rules jar file into Eclipse as a project. I tried different options but I am not getting an option where in I can import the jar into eclipse. It would be great if any one can help me here.

I have already installed the 'Business Rules Service Rule Designer' rules add on to Eclipse from http://businessrules-updates.ng.bluemix.net/